# REACT JS window.beforeunload doesnt work properly

Tags: reactjs

I need to execute an action according the response with fetch code status.
If i got code status 200, window.beforeunload should work.
Else window.beforeunload shouldnot work.

Here is my code`function DialogueEdition(props) {

```
let codeStatusGeneral = 200;
const handleFetch = async () => {
    try {        
        const maReponse = await fetch(`a string`)
            .then(function (response) {
                codeStatusGeneral = response.status;
                return response;
            })
        if (codeStatusGeneral === 200) {
            console.log(403)            
            const recuperation = await maReponse.json();                
        }
        if (codeStatusGeneral === 403) {
            console.log(403)
        }
        if (codeStatusGeneral === 400) {
            console.log("I am DEAD")
        }
        
    } catch (e) {
        
    } finally {
         console.log("finish")
    }
}

handleFetchRefresh = ()=>{
 window.location.reload();
}

if (codeStatusGeneral===200) {
    window.addEventListener("beforeunload", function (e) {
        //many actions
        for (var i = 0; i < 500000; i++) { }
        return undefined;
    });

return (
        <>
            <Button onClick={handleFetch}>
                Fetch
            </Button>
            <Button onclick={handleFetchRefresh}>
                Refresh
            </Button>
        
        </>
    )
```

}`

I made multiple console.log, i notice that the codeStatusGeneral transform in 200 during the refresh. Therefore, it always validates my "if". But it is not what i expected. Please help me.
Thanks in advance.
Sincerely.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Reply to myself, we cant use directly the if condition with the value during the initialization. Otherwise it will take the first value without taking the changes